# Combine 2 "System.out.format" statements into 1

Tags: java, format

How to combine following `System.out.format` statements into 1, so that it prints:

```
1a. Longest string: 'sentence', Size: '8'
```

My code:

```
    System.out.format("1a. Longest string: '%s'",longestString);  
    System.out.format(", Size: '%s'%n",tokens.length);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple:

- Combine the format strings,
- Combine the argument list.

The `format` method goes through the format string, and plugs in the elements of the additional parameter list in places where it sees a format specifier. That is why combining the two is a purely mechanical task.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you could do it like this -

```
System.out.format("1a. Longest string: '%s', Size: '%s'%n",
    longestString, tokens.length);
```